# Why is the apostrophe put before Atta boy?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

> "Little tyke wants his money's worth, just like his father. 'Atta boy,
>   Dudley!" He ruffled Dudley's hair. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

Why is the apostrophe put before Atta boy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*‘Atta boy* is short for *That’s a good boy* or, as [M-W online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attaboy) says, “attaboy: probably alteration of *that’s the boy*”.

Because it's a shortened form, the apostrophe replaces the two missing letters of “that”, just as it replaces the initial “i” in “‘Twas” (“It was”).